# devenv command line build evironment variable / parameter

Tags: c++, command-line, environment-variables, devenv

I am currently using a script to build my project, the script is something like

```
devenv.exe mySolution.sln /Rebuild "Release|Win32" /Project "my project"
```

This is working out great, and I am hoping to expand on it. What I want to do is pass an environment variable or some kind of switch to specify the language. In other words, I would like pass a project setting as a parameter of my command.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

FYI: I have already read http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xee0c8y7(v=vs.80).aspx and I couldn't find anythign useful

Comment: "some kind of switch to specify the language" is vague. Can you explain a bit more?

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately things are not so flexible.

- [msbuild](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171452%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)
- or [NAnt.exe](http://nant.sourceforge.net/) (of CruiseControl fame)
- there is the classic nmake
- cmake aims to generate platform specific solutions/makesfiles from platform independent ones
- A number of plugins exist(ed?) to create make files from Visual Studio projects.

All of the above are better suited to that job